# getCollection() returns 1 value on frontend and multiples on backend

Tags: magento

I have thhis code on my model:

```
$categorias = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
        ->groupByAttribute('name');
```

on my backend page this returns all the products values grouped by name, but if i call this on frontend just return 1 value. What's going on?  If i remove groupByAttribute line work's fine but don't group. I need group.
Ty for help guys

Comment: How many stores do you have in your Magento installation?

Comment: Just 1. The funny is i create one function to get this collection to me, and i call him from backend controller and frontend controller, on backend works fine, frontend return's 1 registry.

Comment: Try to remove the lines ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) and ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) to see how it will behave in the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove your groupByAttribute();

```
$categorias = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
               //removed ->groupByAttribute('name')
        ;
$categorias->getSelect()->group('name');  //added
```

try:

```
 $collection->getSelect()->group($fieldname);
```

if you want to group by more than one field then:

```
 $categorias->getSelect()->group(array($fieldname1, $fieldname2,...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all the categories enabled on the frontend? It could be they are not and therefore only coming up in backend results.

Pesach